# invalid database table structure in sonar 3.6.2

Tags: database, sonarqube

I am installing and configuring sonar 3.6.2 (fresh install, not a migration) - everything went well, until I tried to create new users.
At that moment I got this error:

```
2013.07.23 14:43:42 ERROR o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade  Fail to render: http://svr-dev-20:9000/users
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ORA-00904: "PASSWORD": invalid identifier
: INSERT INTO users (login, name, email, crypted_password, salt, created_at, updated_at, remember_token, remember_token_expires_at, active, auth_type, realm, username, last_login_timestamp, password, id) VALUES('log', 'nam', 'ema', '969f7b154889fb41836385127fecf2d48c6d6ad3', '75227b29dc5d03d5f90dc3c591fd1d9aa96f17e1', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-07-23 14:43:35:981000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF6'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-07-23 14:43:35:981000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF6'), NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ?)
```

I checked the DB and the problem seems to be invalid table structure of table *Users*.
In DB, there is no column "password", as well as "auth_type", "realm", "username", and "last_login_timestamp". All these columns are not present in DB table and yet they are in SQL insert statement.

Did anyone have similar problem? Or how to solve this?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

See the following entry in the SonarQube FAQ : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-FailedtostartSonarQubewithOracleduetobadUSERStablestructure

Comment: sonar starts fine so this is not an issue, also there are no other DB table other than Sonar's, so there cannot be any DB conflicts

Comment: Sonar is reading the metadata of the Oracle DB to dynamically determine which columns are part of a table. And so the only explanation is that Sonar is seeing two USERS tables and merge all those columns.